# Should code from inside of IF's condition run or just evaluate?

Tags: php

I was analyzing some code and came to a part of it (simplified example) which says:

```php
if ( !do_something( 'action-one' ) ) {
  do_something_else();
}
```

Since I was seeing the output of this if statement on page i thought "OK, so `do_something_else` is why this part of page is showing. So I comment it out:

```php
if ( !do_something( 'action-one' ) ) {
  // do_something_else();
}
```

but it is still outputing same content.
Then I comment out the whole if statement, output dissapears. 
So I realized that `do_something` was outputing that content which I wasn't expecting.

Shouldn't `!do_something()` just evaluate to true or false, especially because it has `!` (expecting automatic type conversion)?

This seems like bad practice and something that should be avoided?

Comment: Possibly but hard to say without context, and even then, likely opinion-based. See [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). It could be normal, intended operation, for example... `do_something_else`'s execution being dependent on `do_something`'s success/failure is not that strange.

Comment: So `do_something` returns some value and also outputs something.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is, “the code will run”. The real question is if this function should print something out as well as return a value. If you strive to separate logic from presentation (which I think most would say is good practice), then this function flagrantly violates that principle.

Comment: @ggorlen I have read the side effects article, along with the accepted answer it helped me fill the missing gap. Thanks.
TimMorton Yes, that is the real question as it condition part of if statement doesn't seem as a place intended for that purpose and therefore yes, I would agree that it would be good if functions with side effects are kept outside of condition statements, but once you become aware of it, it gets a lot easier to debug it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if `!do_something()` is true or false your server has to run the function (since you're asking it to run.) So `echo`'s and `print`s will run and will show on your page. If you meant the function returns data: it shouldn't show up in this example (since you're not sending it to the client,) this would mean something more is going on than we can see here.

If you don't want to run the function in your `if` statement you should do something like this:

```
$do_somthing_bool = do_something('action-one'); //Function runs here
    //This will still output echo's and prints but the output (return) of the function 
    // will be stored in $do_somthing_bool
if(!$do_somthing_bool) //Check if the value is false
    //Do something
```

Comment: The first example you mentioned was what I meant. So:
`if ( print_r( 'output') ) { }` will print out output and evaluate the whole function to truthy or falsy, I didn't expect this to be interpreted/ran, but it did and it isn't specific to PHP.
That example code was great, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

do_something  does not return a bool in this case this is why you got a diffrent output